# cPanel - files are not showing in File Manager after copying via SSH / scp

Tags: cpanel

I have just purchased a dedicated server from a UK hosting company that uses cPanel and I have root access

I am using scp to copy a huge (> 2tb) website from another hosting company (1&1 IONOS using Plesk not that it should make any difference)

The files are copying over .. using SSH I can use the "ls" command to list all the files that I've copied over

However, when I use the File Manager option via cPanel interface, I can see the first folder name on the left hand side (i.e. public_html/my-copied-site) but on the right hand window it shows the directory as empty

If I use the "ls" command, I can see the files & folders

if I try an access any of the files directly via a web browser then I get a 403 Forbidden message

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please check with the path where you copied using "pwd" command. It will show you the path in command line

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is the ownership of the folder

Using scp over SSH meant that I was logged in as "root" and therefore the owner of the folders was also "root"

Changing the owner of the folder (using "chown" command) to the account's name resolved the problem

Hope this helps someone out